# Upgrade from Windows 7 Enterprise to Windows 8 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade

I tried to upgrade a Windows 7 Enterprise to Windows 8 Enterprise, however it fails a quarter of the way through the initialization process. Could this have something to do with the Assembly cache?

This is the error:

```
Error  MigGather caught exception: Win32Exception: Falscher Parameter. [0x80070057] void __cdecl Mig::CGACRootEnum::Reset(void)
Error                 MIG    pDoOnlineGather: Gather operation failed. Error: 0x00000004
Error      [0x0800ad] MIG    Callback_GatherOldSysMachineSpecific: Migration phase failed.[gle=0x00000012]
```

I've already attempted a repair install as well. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Do you have any USB3 drivers?

Comment: Yes, I do have USB3 Drivers

Comment: Did the installer mention anything about them being incompatible?

Comment: Not as far as I remember, what leads you to this suspicion?

Comment: I was doing a google search of Windows 7 enterprise to windows 8 enterprise upgrade and I found this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproinstall/thread/c914c8f3-2037-4a6b-bc6b-7f6ba4a94a8b

Comment: Its been reported the HP forums to uninstall any usb 3.0 drivers before upgrading to W8

Comment: interesting, this could be the problem. I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: I might have gotten that wrong, they said to download and install the W8 compatible usb 3.0 driver in W7 before upgrading, but this was for the Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller driver, sorry. Every hardware build is different though, it could be the source of your problem though. If you cannot find a w8 compatible driver you might try uninstalling.

Comment: Nice find, I'll do more research on this tomorrow and hopefully get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Moab - It seems that what you should do is removed ALL USB 3.0 drivers from Windows 7, upgrade to Windows 8, then install the drivers required.  Of course native support within Windows 8 makes this not really required.

Comment: So I don't need the drivers on Windows 8 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that the upgrade media is 100% correct:

- Use [sha1sum](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2004q4/000184.html) to verify your ISO's checksum against the official ISO checksum.
- Burn a new DVD of the Windows 8 installer. Consider using a nonWindows burning tool, such as one from Linux or Mac OS X (e.g. Disk Utility).